# how to access a widget from another class

Tags: qt, qt4

I have two classes(MyWidget,ViewContact). In MyWidget, there is a QLineEdit and QListWidget. The contents in the QListWidget changes dynamically while changes in QLineEditt.

In ViewContact class there is many widgets.The ViewContact class is called by MyWidget class.

```
void MyWidget::viewbind(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
    LblNames *widget = (LblNames*)( listWidget->itemWidget(item) );
    ViewContacts *v=new ViewContacts(widget->getLabelId());
    v->show();
}
```

then ViewContact widget shown as a window,no problem.works fine.
while clicking an update button inside ViewContact class i need to close that window and change the text inside MyWidget .now i just close the ViewContact by `this.close();` function.

I give QLineEdit as public and try to change the text. No errors occur. But no changes display in QLineEdit inside MyWidget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a signal in the ViewContact class and emit a signal while close ViewContact Widget.The signal should contain a string to bind your list view.Before initiating ViewContact Widget from MyWidget ,should connect the signal and setText(const QString) slot.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `MyWidget` as a parent to your `ViewContacts` instance. This will allow you to call a function to update the text (and it will also fix the memory leak which you currently have in your code).

You need a constructor for your ViewContacts that takes both a parent and the labelId.

```
class ViewContacts : public QWidget // or whatever it is, you didn't tell
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    // I don't know the class of "LabelId" either
    explicit ViewContacts(LabelId id, QObject* parent = 0) : QWidget(parent)
    {
        // ...
    }

    void updateTextInParent()
    {
        MyWidget* w = qobject_cast<MyWidget*>(this->parent());
        if (NULL != w)
        {
            // w is a valid pointer to a MyWidget instance
            // you can access any public fields and function through it.
        }
    }
 };
```

You should also use `qobject_cast` or `dynamic_cast` in the snippet you provided because a blind cast is not safe.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a perfect time to take advantage of Qt's signals and slots. You can connect a signal that emits the value you want to update in your MyWidget object, from your ViewContacts widget.

First you'll need to create a signal that emits the changed value when the ViewContacts widget is closed.

Something like:

```
Q_SIGNALS:
    void value_changed_signal( QString value );
```

Next you'll want to add a slot, it can be private, in your MyWidget parent class

The declaration would look something like:

```
private Q_SLOTS:
    void update_text( QString value );
```

Finally, in your MyWidget class, somewhere after you have instantiated your ViewContacts object, connect the signal and slot with something like:

```
connect(new_view_contacts_object, SIGNAL( value_changed_signal( QString ) ), 
    this, SLOT( update_text( QString ) ) );
```